# Overriding default hashing mechanism: cannot redeclare user_hash_password()

Tags: 7, security, users

I have a project that requires a change in the default password encryption mechanism.

The documentation of [password.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/7) states that this can be overridden using the `password_inc` variable. I followed the instructions as stated in the documentation but when trying to change a password on the website following error is generated:

> Cannot redeclare user_hash_password() (previously declared in
>   /.../drupal7/includes/password.inc:207) in
>   /.../drupal7/sites/foo/modules/custom/foo_custom/includes/foo_custom.password.inc
>   ...

I have searched the code for a hardcoded include on includes/password.inc but can't find anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in core uses

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('password_inc', 'includes/password.inc');
```

so I would guess at the cause being a contrib module.

Also just check that the password_inc variable has been updated correctly and not deleted somehow.

Comment: It was a contributed module. I checked the module folder on a multisite installation but forgot about /sites/all. Thanks.

Comment: @Bart For next time: `grep -nr password.inc /path/to/drupal/root` ;)

Comment: Yes, sites/all was the **only** thing I forgot to check :(